# Display recent products(items ) in mvc asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've product table which have `Id(int)`, `ProductName(nvarchar50)`, `Quantity(int)`, `Price(double)`, `SubmittedOn(DateTime)`. I've some data in my table almost 25 products and each of them has `SubmittedOn` date and time when they were entered or saved. Now I just want to show only **10 products** which are recently added in 7 days on my Home Page,

Example: If 1 products has SubmittedOn dateTime of 11 Nov 2015 then I want to show it on my HomePage for **atleast 7 Days and not after that i.e. 17 Nov 2015.**

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Shopping db = new Shopping();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can insert the solution in an answer and remove it from the question (yes, you can "answer to yourself").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this ?
latest 10 added products

```
return View(db.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.SubmittedOn).Take(10).ToList());
```

latest 10 added products within 7 days period

```
var baselineDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
return View(db.Products.Where(x => x.SubmittedOn > baselineDate).OrderByDescending(x => x.SubmittedOn).Take(10).ToList());
```

Comment: Yeah that's works fine. but isn't there anything like comparing the dates ? if the submitted date is less than today date ?

Comment: Got this error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: It's my fault, check the answer again

Answer (score 1):

********* **SOLUTION** *********

Thanks to @Avsenev Slava

```
var baselineDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
return View(db.Products.Where(x => x.SubmittedOn > baselineDate).OrderByDescending(x => x.SubmittedOn).Take(10).ToList());
```